# Загрузка рекламы в приложении

Tags: java, android, встроенная-реклама

У меня есть приложение на android.
Есть реклама за вознаграждения (использую appodeal)
В слушателе такой код

```
if (Appodeal.isLoaded(Appodeal.REWARDED_VIDEO)) {
                    showAd();
                } else {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
```

То есть, если реклама загружена она показывается, если нет, диалоговое окно закрывается. Но есть проблема в том, что можно зайти в приложение и сразу нажать на просмотр рекламы, в случае если она не загрузится, ничего не произойдет. Как вообще на практике это решается? Есть ли какое-то окно, что бы пользователь нажал на кнопку и просто ждал загрузки рекламы или что-то в этом роде.

Так же, инициализация рекламы происходит в этом же активити, потому что я не нашел информации как можно поставить на загрузку рекламу в фоновом режиме.

Прошу объяснить как это правильно настраивается у опытных прогеров

Comment: с appodeal не работал но подозреваю что у них есть какой-то коллБэк который отрабатывает после загрузки рекламы. Как правило это происходит так, инитите рекламу, грузите, отработал коллбэк о загрузке - показали юзеру, начали грузить новую рекламу (для показа в будущем). Предполагаю что там должны быть асинхронные вызовы загрузки (думаю по умолчанию так и есть)

Comment: Если это реклама за вознаграждение, то  доступ к ее показу должен быть только после полной загрузки. Т.е. изначально кнопка "Получить что-то" неактивна, после того как реклама загружена успешно должен сработать "слушатель" загрузки и разблокировать кнопку.

Comment: если надо дождаться загрузки и заблочить интерфейс юзеру пока реклама не загрузится стартуйте например DialogFragment с прогрессБаром и ждите загрузку, потом вырубайте диалог и показывайте рекламу.

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko, блочить не надо, пока поставил вместо кнопки "Смотреть рекламу" - "Реклама загружается". Хотелось бы конечно узнать как пишут рекламный код мастера. Но Ваш подход мне понравился, запишу себе на будущее. Напишите это как ответ, я отмечу его

Comment: @Style-7 не совсем подходит мне. Это что-то можно получить за внутреннюю валюту. При нажатии открывается диалог и есть выбор, реклама или валюта.

Comment: значит пункт реклама заблокирован

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С appodeal не работал но подозреваю что у них есть какой-то коллБэк который отрабатывает после загрузки рекламы. Как правило это происходит так, инитите рекламу, грузите, отработал коллбэк о загрузке - показали юзеру, начали грузить новую рекламу (для показа в будущем). Предполагаю что там должны быть асинхронные вызовы загрузки (думаю по умолчанию так и есть)